# is it safe to delete ~/home/{User}/.cache/

Tags: files, cache, manjaro, delete

IF it's cache it is probably meant to be cleared eventually, but can I just manually delete the whole .cache folder?  It's eating over 10 gigabytes on a 64 GB partition.  I think it is mostly unity game engine and wine.  The os is Manjaro.

Comment: Could always `mv ~/.cache ~/.aside.cache` temporarily

Comment: Yes. But you don't have to wipe it off indiscriminately -- you can leave `~/.cache/fontconfig` in place for instance.

Comment: per your recent edit, are you certain that this cache directory is multiple levels below your home directory?  `~` is frequently used to represent `/home/{user}`, so it's easy to mis-read the title of your question.  Do you have any clues as to what created this extra-level .cache directory?

Comment: doesn't `~` represent the top, or root, directory?  In all my reading that is what was indicated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wouldn't delete "~/home/{User}/.cache/" itself, but it should be fine deleting everything below that.

Edit:
I should add that I'd want to know exactly what's taking up that much space. A handy GUI tool for that is Filelight. Or, from the shell:

du -hs /home/{username}/.cache/*

This will give you directory total sizes in human readable format.

Comment: This is what I recommend doing, especially before you run that backup you've been meaning to do of all those dot directories that you keep putting off for some reason....

Comment: I did use a gui tool, I think it might have even been Firelight to track it down, and that is how I discovered that nearly the entire 10 GB is the unity game engine and wine.